# Submitting an app to Google Play or AppStore

Tags: android, ios

I am working with a developer in another country. Can that developer submit my app (iOS and Android) on my behalf? If so, what information do I need to give him?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an app to be uploaded by someone else under your name, you will have to give them the login credentials to your developer account.

I do not recommend doing this.

Google Play at least does allow you to add other users to your account and control their privilege level from the developer console.

Comment: The other developer would also need the keystore containing the release key; another security issue.

Comment: @323go If he's submitting the app initially he can use his own keystore, or make a new one for this app. OP doesn't seem to want to update an existing app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible. You should give him access to your developer console using this instruction:

1. Open your developer console: https://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Click "Account management"
3. Click "Invite users"
4. Fill developer's google account mail
5. Leave default value for providing finance information (should be disabled)
6. Once developer will  confirm invitation, he will have access to your developer console and your other applications in this console (if they exists). Please note that he will be able to change anything in your applications so it's security risk.

For publishing new app, he will create new project in your console and upload signed draft APK. It's better, if he creates new keystore and key for signing your app. Provide him the following data for the new key:

1. First & Last name
2. Organisation unit
3. Organisation
4. City
5. State
6. Country code

All fields not neccessary. but you should provide at least one field.

**Important:** don't forget to get from developer source code and keystore file with key and keystore password! Otherwise, you won't be able to publish updates.

When developer've maked project and upload APK, you can disable his access, fill application data by yourself (description, screenshots, video link, price, locations, etc) and tap on "Publish". Wow! Your app is avaliable now)

Comment: Thanks a bunch...i greatly appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

He will need your credentials (for iTunesConnect) and also the distribution key to be able to make the archive to upload, unless you provide him the archive of course.